# magento 2 how can i rename invoiceid need to change with orderid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.4

```
    public function execute()
{
    $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
    if ($invoiceId) {
        $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create(
            \Magento\Sales\Api\InvoiceRepositoryInterface::class
        )->get($invoiceId);
        if ($invoice) {
            $pdf = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice::class)->getPdf([$invoice]);
            
            $date = $this->_objectManager->get(
                \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime::class
            )->date('Y-m-d ');
       
            $fileContent = ['type' => 'string', 'value' => $pdf->render(), 'rm' => true];

            return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                'invoice'  . $date  . $invoiceId . '.pdf',
                $fileContent,
                DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                'application/pdf'
            );
        }
    } else {
        return $this->resultForwardFactory->create()->forward('noroute');
    }
}
```

**how can i change invoiceid with order id to rename pdf invoice name**

**** how can i call order number in place of invoiceid ****

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the orderid from invoice object.

```
$invoice->getOrderId();
```

If you want order increment id instead of order id, you have to create order object by order id. In this order object you will get increment id.